# Cannot get dynamic dropdown element for Angular web application to be recognized in Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I have a web application written in Angular I am trying to test in Cypress.   I am having trouble making the dropdown menu show up(circled in image on left).  The dropdown menu shows up when clicking on the 3 dots.  When clicking on the dots, I notice the class attribute in the 'fui-datagrid-action-menu' changes to the class attribute show encircled.  Thus in Cypress, I tried to set the class attribute value to that value encircled.  But when running my test, I get a 'Expected to find element: fui-dropdown, but never found it.'.  Below is a snippet of my Cypress code.  Can anybody suggest what I am doing wrong or is there a better way of coding for a page like this where the Angular elements are dynamic(ie, class attributes change, etc).  Thanks.

[Web Page with Dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Q6i.png)

```
    cy.get('fui-widget-body')
                    .within(() => {
                  cy.log('user found');
                  cy.get('fui-datagrid-action-menu').invoke('show').trigger('mouseover', {force: true});
                  cy.get('fui-datagrid-action-menu').invoke('show').click({ force: true });
                  cy.get('fui-datagrid-action-menu').invoke('attr', 'class', 'fui-datagrid-body-row-action-menu ' +
                    'ng-star-inserted fui-datagrid-action-menu-visible fui-datagrid-action-menu-open')
                    .within(($menu) => {
                      cy.get('fui-dropdown').invoke('show').click({ force: true });
....
```

Comment: Not really an answer as such, but with dynamic class names (I have to test react apps) it's much easier to use dedicated test tags for interacting with objects (data-cy tags are the ones I use). Can you, or one of your devs, add them to the code? It's a much more reliable way to test than relying on class names.

Comment: Thanks,  dev team is working on adding data tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue.  The fui-dropdown element is outside fui-widget-body after hard looks at Chrome developer tools.  It was not easy to determine that as the page is very dynamic.